# Vote-to-close/Canonical questions for "Can't/won't attend conference/ visa issue"

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, canonical-question

People, it's time to start closing-as-(near-)duplicate, and identifying canonical questions and titles, among the following:

1. **[would my paper be published if I faild to attend the conference because of Visa related problems?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/80313/would-my-paper-be-published-if-i-faild-to-attend-the-conference-because-of-visa)** UPDATE: turns out this is more like *"Conference organizer is failing to send me invitation letter which I need for visa; how to proceed; will my paper not be published?"*
2. **["If a paper is accepted as a poster, must you attend the conference?"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/57390/if-a-paper-is-accepted-as-a-poster-must-you-attend-the-conference)**
3. **[What to do if I can't get a visa to attend a conference that accepted my paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17294/what-to-do-if-i-cant-get-a-visa-to-attend-a-conference-that-accepted-my-paper)** which in turn references...
4. **[Etiquette when unable to attend a conference](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13943/etiquette-when-unable-to-attend-a-conference)**

There is a nuance with #2,3,4 that:

a) OP may or may not have coauthor(s)/colleague/supervisor attending who can present (although they may not do a great job) or:

b) rarely confs allow Skype or (recorded-)video presentations, although those may not be great options.

Usually the main, explicit or implicit question is "Will my paper still be published?", but sometimes people are also asking "Can I get a refund on the fee?", and that depends on circumstances (e.g. does a visa refusal or other unforeseen emergency qualify?).

Occasionally people are asking along the lines of "I submitted the same paper to both a journal and a conf as a fallback, unexpectedly got accepted to the journal, now what do I do about the conf?", which is different.

Answer (score 8):

If the questions are identical, definitely close. Saves everyone time.

If questions are similar but subtly different, definitely stay open. The nuance may affect the answer, or may be asking for an entirely different answer (as you point out above).

"Close as duplicate" is a tool for us, the answerers. Do keep in mind, though, that the first customer is the questioner. Unless their question is entirely answered by the earlier post, don't mark as duplicate... give them the answer they're looking for.

That's my take, anyways.

Comment: Which one(s) of those 4 is/are canonical?

Comment: @smci - Generally, it's either the first one or the one with the most comprehensive answer. Specifically for this case, either of the last two would work.

Comment: Turns out #1 is different, see its comments. As to #4 *"Etiquette when unable to attend a conference"* it's a crap title, it's utterly unclear what is being asked.